# map as value of another map in java

Tags: java, dictionary

I need to create map of String,Float inside map with String[] key value.
Here is my way to implement it:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test {
static TreeMap<String,Float> map1;
static TreeMap<String[],TreeMap<String,Float>> map2;
public static void main (String[] args){
        map1 = new TreeMap<String,Float>();
        map2 = new TreeMap<String[],TreeMap<String,Float>>();
        map1.put("key",1.0f);
        map2.put(new String[]{"String1","String2"},map1);
        System.out.println(map2);
    }
}
```

It compiles without any troubles.
But after starting this program I got ClassCastException :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; can
not be cast to java.lang.Comparable
        at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1290)
        at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:538)
        at Test.main(Test.java:9)
```

Could you please explain me where is my mistake and how I can fix it?

Comment: Implement the comparator by yourself in the code... because tree map stores the keys in sorted order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you construct a `TreeMap` instance without passing a `Comparator` instance to the constructor, the key of your map must implement `Comparable`. Since arrays don't implement `Comparable`, you can't use this constructor for a `TreeMap` would key is an array. You must pass a `Comparator<String[]>` to your `TreeMap`.

```
Comparator<String[]> comparator = ...
map2 = new TreeMap<String[],TreeMap<String,Float>>(comparator);
```

Comment: thanks, now I replace TreeMap with LinkedHashMap and it works.

Comment: @Roki20121 Actually with LinkedHashMap it doesn't work and can't work, since arrays don't override `equals` and `hashCode` of `Object` class. Therefore if you put something in the map like this - `map2.put(new String[]{"aa","bb"},someValue);` - and later try to get it from the map with - `map2.get(new String[]{"aa","bb"})`, you will get null, since the two String arrays are different objects, and they are not equal to each other. Perhaps you should use a `List<String>` instead of `String[]` for the key.